# Point readout of raster data in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point

I'm having a mental block and was wondering if there was any way to click on an individual raster grid cell in ArcGIS and create a sample point readout of the data (other than in the identify tool).  I want to place sample points of numerous grid points similar to this (this is a different program).

[image: sample points]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another slightly different option would be to extract the raster cell values to an existing point feature class using [Extract Values to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm).  This will allow many point features to get the raster cell value.  First, digitize points where you want the point labels to show, use the Extract Values tool, and finally label the point layer by the new added cell value field in the output feature class.

> Extracts the cell values of a raster based on a set of point features
>   and records the values in the attribute table of an output feature
>   class.

Comment: both this tool and the Get Cell Value tool would work, but I chose to accept this answer since it can many point features can be done at once.  T/u

Answer (score 1):

I think the tool that you may be looking for is [Get Cell Value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-cell-value.htm) which:

> Retrieves the value of a given pixel using its x, y coordinates.

Comment: This will get the cell value at a x/y location but a point either graphic or within a point feature class will need created to label the get cell value.